# Character Jump (AddForce) unusual behavior near objects in unity 2D

Tags: unity, 2d

My character object has a single jump mechanics and I just noticed the whenever I press the jump button many times quickly in which the character is near a "Platforms like staircase, boxes or even sometime near the edge of a platform (while also being up in the air and pressing jump many times when colliding)" it starts to fly off beyond my jump force. Can anyone help me to fix the physics? Thanks!

My Jump system code sample:

```
Rigidbody2D mybody;
public float jumpforce;
public bool isGrounded = false;
public Transform feet;
public LayerMask groundlayers;
public float groundradius = 1f;
bool Jumprequest;
    
void Start () {
    mybody = GetComponent<Rigidbidy2D>();
}

void Update () {
    JumpRequest();
}

void FixedUpdate() {
    Jump();
    JumpOptimization();
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(feet.position, groundradius, groundlayers);
}

public void JumpRequest() {
    if (CrossPlatformInputManager.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded) {
        isGrounded = false;
        Jumprequest = true;
    }
}

void Jump() {
    if (Jumprequest) {
        mybody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpforce) , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    Jumprequest = false;
}

void JumpOptimization() {
    if (mybody.velocity.y < 0) {
        mybody.gravityScale = Fallmultiplier;
    }
    else {
        mybody.gravityScale = 1;
    }
}
```

Here is a sample picture that might help:
The red line shows when character collided with an object while `addforce` is added upwards and pressing
Jump button repeatedly at the same time, the character flies off beyond my jump force.

[image]

Comment: You should as well not set the isGrounded manually in the jump - it gets overwritten anyway by your groundCheck method afterwards right away.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. In the future, please consider formatting your code when posting - a consistent & clean style is much easier to read which in turn makes it easier for the community to spot errors & provide answers. Good luck with your game!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This should ensure you have no preexisting upwards momentum when you jump**:

```
void Jump()
{
    if (Jumprequest)
    {
        mybody.velocity = Vector3.zero;    // <======= ADD THIS LINE
        mybody.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpforce) , ForceMode2D.Impulse);
...
```